# A Weird Binomial Distribution Problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I was just looking into a Bayesian model for flipping a coin. Let $\theta$ denote the bias of the coin. A bias of $1$ will always land on heads $h$ and $0$ will aleays land on tails $t$. It was said that a good candidate for the likelihood is the binomial distribution
$$p(h\mid\theta) = \frac{n!}{h!(n - h)!}\theta^h(1 - \theta)^{(n-h)}$$

But then I noticed... If I were to set $\theta = 1$ then this gives
$$\frac{n!}{h!(n - h)!}\cdot 1^h\cdot(1 - 1)^{(n-h)} = 0$$

So that means that the probability of getting heads, given the bias is $1$ is zero? I am very confused by this. How can this be?

Comment: A coin with $\theta=1$ doesn´t exist. The "coin" has to have only one side. This is more a ball than a coin.

Comment: In most usual usages we seldom take care of the extreme values of $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = 1$. If you really want to incorporate that into this formula, you should note that $\theta = 1$ will give $p(n|\theta) = 1$ and $0$ otherwise, and you just have to define the $0^0$ issue if you insist to write this. If you accept that $p(n|\theta) = \theta^n$ then there is no problem at all.

Comment: @BGM how will $\theta=1$ give $p(n\mid \theta) = 1$ with what I have shown?

Comment: @callculus That's starting to make sense. But you could have a weighted coin to make the bias change so if you weighted the coin so much that it wouldn't spin then why is the result zero. I know it doesn't exist but in theory, $\theta = 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $p = 1$ but it doesn't?